# How to return text from nokogiri without parsing it

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I have html that looks like this:

```
<textarea id='embed'>
   <iframe frameborder='0' width='728' height='450' src='http://somelink'>
   </iframe> some more text
</textarea>
```

My code is:

`doc.at('textarea[@id="embed"]').content`

however this returns `some more text`

I want to fetch the entire text area (including the `iframe` link as it is). So finally I want this :

```
<iframe frameborder='0' width='728' height='450' src='http://somelink'>
   </iframe> some more text
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `.inner_html`.

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'nokogiri'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> noko = Nokogiri::HTML("<textarea id='embed'>
[2] pry(main)*    <iframe frameborder='0' width='728' height='450' src='http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xvnu79'>
[2] pry(main)*    </iframe> some more text
[2] pry(main)* </textarea>");
[3] pry(main)> noko.css("#embed").inner_html
=> "<iframe frameborder=\"0\" width=\"728\" height=\"450\" src=\"http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/xvnu79\">\n   </iframe> some more text\n"
```

Edit: you can use `.inner_html` with the XPath selector you have above too.